# Restore a windows 10 PC without a search bar

Tags: windows-10

I would like to do a system restore a windows 10  cyberpowerpc but 2 things are happening.

1. the search doesnt work. I cant click on the search input for whatever reason.
2. PC keeps booting in safe mode.
   All instructions on restoring a PC start with going to search bar and typing restore.
   Is there another way to wipe the OS and restore it to the system default.

I cant access ms-settings application or the settings screen

Comment: I am curious, you have asked and answered questions on several stackexchange sites, so you have experience on stackexchange, why did you choose serverfault instead of the probably more appropriate site superuser?

Comment: I recommend doing a clean install. Windows' self-recovery is rather limited in what it can fix.

Answer (score 0):

No need to type restore on the search bar. Open directly Settings -> Update & Security -> Recovery. Select Get Started on the Reset this Pc category.

Another method is to open Command prompt as administrator, type `systemreset` and go through the options to reset the PC.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run the settings, ms-settings or any of that.  Seems like there would be a way to recover before windows boots.

Comment: @TommieJones See edit.